# use of "might" & "might be"

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Please clarify the situations we use "might" & "might be" in this sentence:

> Since they have mentioned about [cargo] securing/lashing on trucks also **it might useful** for ADV project team who directly get involved with lashing but not us.

Answer (score 1):

might be + adj
might + verb

might describes a slight possibility.

in your case, it should be it might be useful for ADV...

Answer (score 0):

It should be might be because of the possibility of something happening later, which require a verb.

> In your case might+ verb i.e. 
>   might+ be will right.